# Is it guaranteed that google maps my location button position is fix?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have embedded a `MapFragment` into one of my activities. I want to add an `ImageButton` on the map, with same styling as the "**My location button**", right under it.

Can I trust on **Google Maps API** that the position of this button is always at the **top right corner**, regardless of device density, resolution or orientation? I made some tests with some devices but I cannot try all devices of course. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've just found it!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity?hl=en

> **My Location button**
>
> The My Location button appears in the top right corner of the screen
>   only when the My Location layer is enabled.

It's not "guaranteed", since the specifications can change in time, but at least it's documented.